# I need to run the same script multiple times in parallel with log management

Tags: bash, shell, sh, ksh

I need to run the same script multiple times in parallel with log management of each script execution

I need an optimal method please?

```
script name :  script.sh

logs :  log_execution1.log  log_execution2.log ... 
or
logs :  log_execution-PID.log  log_execution-PID.log ...
```

thanks

Comment: You did updated in the @mouviciel 's answer you want to use PID instead of incremented variable, your example insist that you want to use incremented value. Please let us know what you what to do exactly, and update your question accordingly.

Comment: both work for me, and give the same result.
I changed my method of development by naming my log files by PID
Where is the problem. and why -1... 
please remove your dislike. Thanks

Comment: votes only can be changed if question get edited.

Comment: i edited it...or logs : log_execution-PID.log log_execution-PID.log ...

Answer (score 3):

This can be done around a loop:

```
$ ntimes=42
$ for i in $(seq 1 $ntimes) ; do (script.sh > log_execution$i.log &) ; done
```

Comment: many thanks good method. but i used PID instead of the incremented value

Answer (score 0):

I did it like that :
it's work fine now.

```
while [ -e file.dat ]
do
./a.ksh
sleep 5
done
```

file : a.ksh

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "Hello StackOverFlow" > log_execution-$$.log
exit 0
```

Result

```
-rw-r--r--   1 aai      aai      22 Apr 19 11:11 log_execution-27310.log
-rw-r--r--   1 aai      aai       0 Apr 19 11:11 log_execution-26005.log
-rw-r--r--   1 aai      aai      22 Apr 19 11:11 log_execution-27327.log
```

thank you for your help